# How to find the PCI_ID of the port that a certain USB device is plugged into

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, pci

I would like to find the pci_id  of `Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p` in the output below.

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 10, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=ftdi_sio, 12M
```

I can't seem to find any way to map this to any of these three:

```
lspci -nn | grep USB
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI [8086:8c31] (rev 05)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 [8086:8c2d] (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 [8086:8c26] (rev 05)
```

Comment: You might try `udevadm info -a -p /sys/class/tty/ttyUSB0` which goes up the tree showing device and vendor attributes.

Comment: @meuh - another useful weapon for my arsenal, but in the task at hand I actually prefer what I scripted - *MUCH* easier to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more googling, some thought and a bit of trial & error I came up with this:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ -h /sys/class/tty/ttyUSB0 ] || exit 1
pci_id=$( /usr/bin/realpath /sys/class/tty/ttyUSB0 | awk -F'/' '{print gensub(/....:(.*)/, "\\1","1",$5)}' )
usb_id=$( lspci -n| awk -v id=$pci_id '$0 ~ id {print $3}' )
```

which, when run, gives me the desired result for the scenario above:

```
./get_usb.sh
8086:8c26
```

Answer (score 1):

If the Debain `discover` package is available, it will give you the information you are seekiing

`# discover --vendor-id --model-id pci | grep USB`

Comment: Nice tool I hadn't stumbled upon; but it doesn't tell me which of the three my USB UARTs are connected to.