# Find out PCI(e) ID of a working PCI(e) device, in this case a USB controller

Tags: linux, kvm, qemu, pci, pci-passthrough

I inserted a mPCIe card - a USB controller - into one of my computers mPCIe slots.
Attached USB devices are shown by `lsusb` and everything is working fine.

Now I'm running KVM/qemu and I want to pass-through not just single USB devices but the USB controller as PCIe device to a virtual machine - as I already did with on-board NICs (also PCIe).

So I figured the USB controller is announcing itself as a PCI connected device when calling `lspci` - but it isn't:

```
# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Mullins IOMMU
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h (Models 30h-3fh) Host Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:08.0 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Kabini/Mullins PSP-Platform Security Processor
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 39)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 42)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:14.7 SD Host controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SD Flash Controller (rev 01)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 5
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
```

The computer is a PC engines APU2 embedded computer, AMD based (https://www.pcengines.ch/apu2.htm) - running Debian Linux.

`lsusb` shows the connected USB devices being connected to the USB controller in question.

Question: How can I find out which PCI(e) ID/device my USB controller is connected to in order to know which one to pass-through so it pops up in my virtual machine as native PCI(e) device?

I figured potentially by the USB bus ID of what `lsusb` spits out - however that's as far as I got.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/469912/430794

Comment: Thanks! I now tried `udevadm info -a -p` as well as `discover` and both lead me to the internal USB controller: `00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 39)` - however that one is also listed when I remove the mPCIe controller card which really confuses me.

Comment: What if you do `lspci > ~/lspci_before`, then shutdown and add (or remove) the PCI card and `lspci > ~/lspci_after`, then `diff ~/lspci_before ~/lspci_after`.

Comment: I'm having two of the same kind embedded devices and both lspci commands show (more or less) the same output (more or less because there's difference in revisions of the onboard SATA controller).